# Is there a way to use CSS -transform and not affect children elements

Tags: css

I created a [mockup](http://jsfiddle.net/Vyaf3/3/) to demonstrate my problem. I fear the solution falls in what I did with the first example (box1).

Just not sure why I can't apply a css transform to a parent element and avoid applying it to the child element or at least override it.

Let me know if there is a way to get the effect of the first example using the transform property. I don't want the second image to be scaled as well. Just the parent div.

---

**Note**

I'm trying to use this property to enable GPU acceleration.

Comment: set overflow to auto on .box1, .box2

Comment: You want the image to stay with fixed dimensions above the animated div?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gnrlbzik/5Q8EC/ let me know if this the effect that you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to use -transform to get the GPU performance perk. I guess I'll continue to use the width animation: http://jsfiddle.net/Vyaf3/22/ but with applying a css3 property that would enable the GPU acceleration.

Answer (score 2):

Have not played with this in any other browser but the chrome.

But it looks like overflow hidden set on parent element implies resizing inheritance on image.

So if you set overflow auto on the boxes to which animation is applied, it should fix the resizing inheritance.

http://jsfiddle.net/gnrlbzik/5Q8EC/ tests the overflow set to auto, that keeps image dimensions in tact.

Comment: I actually added another div to it because I couldn't have the scrollbar showing up: http://jsfiddle.net/5Q8EC/8/ Thanks for the lead you gave me though. Interesting how overflow affects the inheritance though.

Comment: yeah i was thinking about another wrapper as well, fearing those pesky scroll bars : )

Comment: Sorry - at first glance I didn't realize you changed the animation. The whole point was to keep using the CSS transform. changing it to width really just moves it to what I had for the first example. Again, sorry about that.

Comment: I think I'm going to use the width animation - but use a different (unobtrusive) property to enable GPU performance. Thanks for your hard work - keeping your answer as +1, but for now - just going to go with the fiddle I posted as a solution.

Comment: To tell you the truth, scale(), after reading up on it, looks like there is no way, at least with this implementation, as it scales entire parent/child node relationshipt, hence all the children... interesting... although makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

To be semantic I don't think you should be able to stop it from transforming a child element being you are transforming/scaling it's container, not resizing it. A transform is not just animating the width like the example on box 1, it scales the x.

I believe this question is about trying to gain some performance boost by using features that use the GPU to process animations. This is possible, I believe, by effectively treating the elements as an image that the GPU then animates. Thus you are not able to have an element inside that dynamically keeps its size/shape during an animation. Maybe there is a way to counter the animation by transforming the element within that you would like to keep static, but this will probably not be efficient nor effective.

***Note**: I am not well versed in the actual technology webkit uses to render these transformations. So sorry if the finer details of the rendering are not quite accurate. I will update this if anyone comments with a better description of how transform works.*

Comment: You are accurate - I am using this to get the GPU performance perk. So maybe I just trick it into using it.

Comment: yeah, scale does what it suppose to, scale parent and it's children.